# Kubernetes deployment - instantly replace all pods

Tags: kubernetes

Our application consists of pods that handle asynchronous tasks from a queue. They might take up to half an hour to finish a task, but once sent a SIGINT or SIGTERM, will not pick up any new tasks.

What we want to achieve with a Kubernetes deployment is that all existing pods are sent the signal to terminate, and without waiting for them to be stopped, create the new pods.

Based on [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-update-deployment), I think this can be achieved by setting `maxSurge` and `maxUnavailable` both to 100%. Would this achieve our goal?

Comment: look into deployment strategies. your link already talks abt it.

Comment: That's what I'm looking into and what I linked in my question. But what's unclear from the documentation for me, is at what point Kubernetes waits with progressing. Using recreate seems like it waits for all pods to finish being down before adding new ones.

Comment: recreate wont help your case. As u mentioned use rolling update and configure the maxUnavailable to be 0 and maxSurge to be ur no of replicas. This will create new pods equal to ur surge and make sure that the switch to ur new pods happen only when all the new pods are available as controlled by maxUnavailable.